# Search sub string then Replace Line in a file without regex

Tags: bash, perl, search, str-replace

I want to run a script to search the /etc/bash.bashrc file for the substring

```
PS1=
```

and replace the entire line with:

```
 PS1='\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]\u\[\e[m\]:\[\e[32m\]\W\[\e[m\]>\\$ '
```

This new line is intended to change the cli prompt.

I have tried and tried sed in a bash script but I couldn't get the regex right.

[Edit] This code now works:

```
#!/bin/bash

custom_prompt='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[36;40m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]:\[\e[92m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[92m\]\\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]>\[\e[m\]\'

### Setup Bash Prompt
# replace each \ for double \\ in the prompt string
sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')

# add this to  /etc/bashrc for global effect
sed  -i "s/PS1=.*/PS1=\"$sed_custom_prompt\"/" testrc
```

The only problem is that it does `PS1= " string "`
rather than  `PS1 = ' string '` with back tics.

I need a simple old fashioned non-regex script that finds a string and replaces a line in a file.  Regex can find the string but my original statement messed up the substitution.

I don't care if it is perl, awk or bash.  I just need something that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape every `\` to make sure they aren't lost.

EDIT: The PS1 string should be wrapped with double quotes as well.

```sh
$ custom_prompt="\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]\u\[\e[m\]:\[\e[32m\]\W\[\e[m\]>\\$ "
$ sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')
$ sed -i "s/PS1=.*/PS1=\"$sed_custom_prompt\"/" testrc
$ source testrc
laptop@user:~>$
```

The following code works on my laptop. The problem was in last `\` character in the string of your `PS1` variable (I removed it):

```sh
#! /bin/bash
custom_prompt='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[36;40m\]\u\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]:\[\e[92m\]\w\[\e[m\]\[\e[92m\]\\$\[\e[m\]\[\e[93m\]>\[\e[m\] '

### Setup Bash Prompt
# replace each \ for double \\ in the prompt string
sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')

# add this to  /etc/bashrc for global effect
sed -i  "s/PS1=.*/PS1='$sed_custom_prompt'/" testrc

exit 0
```

p.s. I personally like to add the time to the PS1 so I know how long ago a command is exited. Also, you can immediately time stuff if you add it (`\D{%H}:\D{%M}`).

Comment: I tried that.  I added a line of code that automated the substitution.    sed_custom_prompt=$(<<<"$custom_prompt" sed 's/\\/\\\\/g') same as you
but that didn't work.

Comment: OK I will try that tomorrow (it is late here).

Comment: Your code almost works.  I edited the question to show the problem.  I can't figure out how to write ' rather than " to the file.

Comment: I get the right string replacement but it has PS1 = " string " instead of PS1 =  ' string '  . I can't figure out how to end up with ' ' rather than " ".

Comment: @dazz that was quite easy, you only had to change `\"` for `'` in the last regex. I've fixed it for you.

Comment: OK. I thought that would have the effect o escaping the $ variable but it works. Thanks.

Comment: Within a string: only if the most outer quotes are single, no variables are parsed. Of course it's different if you have `echo "test $(echo '$var')", since `$()` is a new shell.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing scripts to replace the existing `PS1` jest overwrite it it's much simpler.

```
echo PS1="This is my prompt" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

This wil append the new PS1 to the end of the file and since this in the end it will overwrite the default PS1 initialization.

Comment: Thanks for you input.  The reason I didn't choose this as an answer is maintainability.  If anyone came back to the config file, they would scan down the file until they found the line they were looking for, and edit that.  They might not get to the end of the file to see the overwrite line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
replace='PS1="\[\e[36m\]\h\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\e[33m\]\u\[\e[m\]:\[\e[32m\]\W\[\e[m\]>\\$ "'
perl -i -spe 's/^PS1=.*$/$repl/' -- -repl="$replace" -- /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Note: Maybe remove the `-i` (in-place edit) in the first run to check if it works.